# Why is $\frac{\vert x \vert}{\vert x-1 \vert -1}$ not an indeterminate form?

Tags: calculus

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form), there is an example as follows:

*An expression that arises by ways other than applying the algebraic limit theorem may have the same form of an indeterminate form. However it is not appropriate to call an expression "indeterminate form" if the expression is made outside the context of determining limits. For example, $0/0$ which arises from substituting $0$ for $x$ in the equation $f(x)=\vert x \vert / (\vert x - 1 \vert - 1)$ is not an indeterminate form since this expression is not made in the determination of a limit (it is in fact undefined as division by zero).*

I cannot understand why $f(x)=\vert x \vert / (\vert x - 1 \vert - 1)$ is not an indeterminate form since $\vert x \vert \rightarrow 0$ and $\vert x - 1 \vert - 1 \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. And both functions are continuous at $p\in(-\delta,\delta)$ for $\delta > 0$ (so the limits exist even for $p=0$), moreover differentiable except for $x=0,1$, respectively. These facts imply that we can use several tools for evaluating the indeterminate form. For instance, both the denominator and numerator are linear (same growth rate) hence $f(x)$ does not have a limit at $x=0$ in the sense of growth rate (growth rate of the numerator at $x=0$ varies depending on the orientation).

Comment: It's saying the term indeterminate form only makes sense in the context of talking about limits.

Comment: The point seems to be that $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{|x|}{|x-1|-1}$ is an indeterminate form, but $\frac{|x|}{|x-1|-1}$ without the limit is not an indeterminate form (and I agree with this point).

Comment: @Alan I understand. Thanks.

Comment: @GregMartin: Aren't they saying that it's the expression $\frac{0}{0}$ (rather than the expression $\frac{|x|}{|x-1|-1}$) that's not an indeterminate form?